Abel test for uniform convergence
Considering $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ ; $(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ sequences of functions of $U$ in $\mathbb{C}$ with:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n$  converges uniformly
$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|g_n(z)-g_{n+1}(z)|$ converges pointwise and its sum is bounded
$(g_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is uniformly bounded

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_ng_n$ converges uniformly $(\ast)$
By summation by parts ($F_n(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{N}f_n(z)$):
\begin{align*}
|\sum_{k=n}^{m}f_k(z)g_k(z)| \leq \sum_{k=n}^{m}|g_k(z)-g_{k+1}(z)||F_k(z)|+|F_{n-1}(z)||g_{n}(z)-g_{m+1}(z)|+|g_{m+1}(z)||F_{m}(z)-F_{n-1}(z)|
\end{align*}
I cannot see how only pointwise convergence of $|g_n(z)-g_{n+1}(z)|$ should lead to $(\ast)$; any suggestions?

Let $F_N (z) = \sum_{n=N}^{+\infty} f_n (z)$, and $f_n (z) = F_n (z) - F_{n+1} (z)$. (This is different from yours. As $N \to +\infty$, my $F_N (z) \to 0$ uniformly, therefore, it's easier to be used.)
$$
\left|\sum_{k=n}^{m}f_k(z)g_k(z)\right|
\leq \sum_{k=n+1}^{m} |F_k(z)| |g_k(z)-g_{k+1}(z)| + |F_n(z)||g_{n}(z)| + |F_{m+1}(z)||g_m(z)|.
$$

The last two terms are uniformly small because $g$ is uniformly bounded and $F\to0$ uniformly.
The first term is also uniformly small because $\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty} |g_k(z) - g_{k+1}(z)|$ is bounded and $F \to 0$ uniformly.

Therefore, $\left|\sum_{k=n}^{m}f_k(z)g_k(z)\right|$ is uniformly small, so $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} f_n(z) g_n(z)$ converges uniformly.
Reference: Abel's Test for Uniform Convergence - ProofWiki
